# IndexError: list index out of range after first loop object

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, color-ramp

When I run the below loop, only the first list entry gets applied the Elevation #10 ColorRamp and transparency.  After it loops back to the second entry I get the following error:

> cr = p.listColorRamps('Elevation #10')[0]   IndexError: list index out
> of range

Been staring at this for hours, hoping fresh eyes can see something obvious.  I'm new to ArcPy.

```
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"Z:/ArcGIS_Modules/GIS_Automation_Basics/Automation_Map/Automation_Map.aprx")
m = p.listMaps("Map")[0]

for region in regions:
    l = mp.listLayers("USGS_1_" + region)[0]
    cr = p.listColorRamps('Elevation #10')[0]
    sym = l.symbology
    if sym.colorizer.type == 'RasterStretchColorizer':
        sym.colorizer.colorRamp = cr
        l.symbology = sym
        l.transparency = 50
        input("done!")
p.save()
```

---

I had to move the `cr = p.listColorRamps('Elevation #10')[0]` above the loop.  can anyone tell me why it can't go get the color ramps a second time within a loop?

Comment: so I just added a line to print all the mp.listColorRamps() and it gets cleared the second go around, what am I missing here?  This has to be by design?  Something I'm not understanding.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to revise it to just represent your current question.  The original error was just telling you that the list of color ramps did not contain one named 'Elevation #10' so try printing the whole list to see what it does contain.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thats how I was able to figure out what was happening, the whole list gets wiped after the first loop.  When I printed the list turning the initial loop, it shows the full list of color ramps, but then, on the second round, there is nothing in it, so it errors out.

Comment: I missed seeing your first comment when I made mine. It makes sense to pull that line outside the loop but it’s not immediately obvious why the list becomes empty so if you want to ask about that please present just the code you’re currently stuck on and the output of print statements within it.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, your code should work. However, best practice is to *not* re-set variables where they'd end up getting the same value. Bringing this above your loop is the correct way forward.

From the error you're getting, `IndexError: list index out of range`, it sounds like the project (`p = arcpy.....`) isn't returning any values for the `listColorRamps`. Again, I can't explain why it would stop evaluating after the first loop, because in theory, it should. You could attempt to debug it by doing `prints` or setting breakpoints and debugging and seeing what the value is inside the loop, or you could log a Tech Support case. Either way, it may not get you very far for the amount of effort you'd put in.